# class.getClassLoader.getResource() returns null

Tags: java, classloader

Previously I built single jars with ant, for each application i wanted from my project and calling the application with java -jar application-name. 
I have now moved to using gradle and having a single jar and call the applications with 
java -cp fullpath-to-class.

Everything works as expected for all but one application where i now get a 
null pointer exception trying to load the resources required.

If I move the files into the directory of the class which is looking for the files everything is good once again , but having them in a different directory seems to be problematical.

Have you any suggestions on the best approach to

A. debugging this effectivey

B. Having the file in a separate directory

Answer (score 0):

> Have you any suggestions on the best approach to A. debugging this effectively

1. Use `jar -tvf ...` to check that the missing resource is actually in the JAR file, and that it has the correct pathname in the JAR.file
2. Use a debugger, and set a breakpoint on the code that is trying to load the resource.  Single step until you get to the point where you have the *absolute* resource path.  Check it.

> B. Having the file in a separate directory

Umm.  I'm not sure what your actual problem is, but my guess is that it is to do with resolving relative resource pathnames.  I suggest using absolute resource pathnames instead.

I guess the problem could be in the way you are building the JAR file, but you've not provided any concrete details of how you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried ti debug it with break points - but it works in the IDE just not in the gradle created jar.

Comment: You need to run the gradle created JAR using a debugger!  Read up on how to attach a debugger to a JVM.